# How to convert a C file to a .m file in bash?

Tags: bash, converters

To convert a C file from m file I use

```
m4 prog.m > prog.s
gcc -o prog prog.s
./prog
```

Is it possible to go the other way ?

I know you can do

```
gcc -S prog.c
```

to make it a .s file but how do I get it into a .m ?

Comment: Is that first line supposed to  be `m4 prog.m > prog.c`?

Comment: No. What i posted was to go from a  .m to a .c. With .m file you have to convert to a .s using m4 prog.m > prog.s . Then once in assembly, you have to convert this to C using gcc.   The question i asked was how to go the opposite way from a .c to a .m  but the answer below laid out the problem quite well.

Comment: Are you saying that gcc converts assembly language to C? Even if it did, you don't refer to `prog.s` after you generate it.

Comment: Is the output of `m4 program.m` C source code or assembly language source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, and it's not clear why you would need to. The `.m` file isn't really related to C; it just contains certain macros that are expanded by `m4` to produce a new text file. You couldn't tell from the output file alone which text was produced by the macros.

A simple analogy is a pair of sums like `1 + 3` and `2 + 2`. The two sums (representing the `.m` files) both evaluate to 4, but only given 4, there is no way you could tell if it was produced from `1 + 3` or `2 + 2`.

Alternatively, you could generate any sum you want (`0 + 4`, `1 + 3`, `1.5 + 2.5`), and no one could say it was a "wrong" sum. Likewise, you could produce any one of an infinite number of valid `.m` files that, when run through `m4`, would give you back the original `.c` file, but it wouldn't really be a useful thing to do.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you.